# Как сделать сайт на wordpress на 3-х языка?

Tags: html, wordpress

Нужно сделать сайт-портфолио на трёх языках. И интегрировать на WordPress. Просто менять контент, можно с помощью плагинов. Но задача состоит в том, чтобы русский сайт продвигать на yandex.ru, а иностранные - на google.com.

Как это правильно сделать? Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Может PHP gettext ?

Comment: "Но задача стоит в том что бы русский сайт продвигать на yandex.ru а иностранные google.com" - отсутствие запятых  намеренно?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте WPML - самый мощный плагин для перевода контента. Каждая запись или страница могут быть на любом количестве языков. Переводы можно размещать в разных поддоменах, например:

ru.mysite.org

en.mysite.org

es.mysite.org

Это решает задачу продвижения языковых версий в разных поисковиках.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно сделать сайт-портфолио на трёх языках. И интегрировать на
>   WordPress.

Все не так. Ничего делать не нужно чтобы потом "интегрировать" в WordPress. Нужно СРАЗУ сделать на WordPress мультиязычный сайт-потфолио.

> Просто менять контент, можно с помощью плагинов.

Для смены контента плагины не нужны. Это основной функционал любой CMS, который заложен даже в эту аббревиатуру.
А вот чтобы сделать мультиязычный сайт, где нужен контент для разных языков - для того уже нужны плагины.

Бесплатные плагины для создания мультиязычности:

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wpglobus/

> Но задача состоит в том, чтобы русский сайт продвигать на yandex.ru, а
>   иностранные - на google.com.

Это уже к WordPressне относится. Это SEO. Со стороны ВП никаких препятствий этому нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш сайт-портфолио, то количество страниц небольшое. В таком случае можно прибегнуть к помощи плагинов. Например, [Weglot Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/Weglot/).

Я когда диплом делал - использовал его.